# Can not upgrade Server Edition

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, server, upgrade

Can someone tell me how can I upgrade my ubuntu server 10.04 to ubuntu server 10.10?

I try:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Output:

```
Checking for a new ubuntu release
No new release found


sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is you are in a LTS version and 10.10 is a normal version.

Here are the steps:

**Be sure that you apply all updates to your current version of Ubuntu before you upgrade:**

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now perform [this procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaverickUpgrades):

> Network upgrade for Ubuntu servers (Recommended)
>
> 1. Install `update-manager-core` if it is not already installed:
>
>    `sudo apt-get install update-manager-core`
> 2. Edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and set `Prompt=normal`.
> 3. Launch the upgrade tool:
>
>    `sudo do-release-upgrade`
> 4. Follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: If I have to stop the do-release-upgrade process because of power failure or some other reason is there a way I can set back things to original

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo do-release-upgrade` alone. If you are going to merge commands in one line, it should be like this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Notice the two ampersands.

Answer (score 0):

You broke the chaining of the two commands that were right (use `&&` or just split them over two lines)

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: didn't help me... I edited my question... hope it helps