# Distribution upgrade problem "No new release found"

Tags: 11.04, upgrade

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04. The update manager once found the new release 'oneiric', and still shows up this screen when I log on use ssh:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 11.04 (GNU/Linux 2.6.38-14-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

New release 'oneiric' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Last login: Wed Apr 25 16:22:48 2012 from ***
```

But I didn't upgrade then, and change my apt sources. And now I cannot upgrade to 'oneiric'. `do-relase-upgrade` shows:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new ubuntu release
No new release found
$
```

And `apt-get dist-upgrade` shows:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$
```

I can successfully update all my packages.

---

File contents of source.list:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
## See sources.list(5) for more information, especialy
# Remember that you can only use http, ftp or file URIs

deb http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ natty main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ natty main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ natty-security universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ natty-security universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ natty-backports universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ natty-backports universe main multiverse restricted


# deb http://ubuntu.dormforce.net/ubuntu/ lucid main universe restricted multiverse
# deb-src http://ubuntu.dormforce.net/ubuntu/ lucid main universe restricted multiverse
# deb http://ubuntu.dormforce.net/ubuntu/ lucid-security universe main multiverse restricted
# deb-src http://ubuntu.dormforce.net/ubuntu/ lucid-security universe main multiverse restricted
# deb http://ubuntu.dormforce.net/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe main multiverse restricted
# deb-src http://ubuntu.dormforce.net/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe main multiverse restricted

# CDROMs are managed through the apt-cdrom tool.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com lucid partner
# deb http://archive.canonical.com lucid-security partner
# deb http://archive.canonical.com lucid-updates partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com lucid partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com lucid-security partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com lucid-updates partner


#medibuntu repo
# deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ lucid free non-free
# deb-src http://packages.medibuntu.org/ lucid free non-free

# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main #Third party developers repository
deb http://mirrors.sohu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted multiverse universe
deb-src http://mirrors.sohu.com/ubuntu/ natty main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.sohu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://mirrors.sohu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.sohu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe main multiverse restricted
```

File contents of /etc/update-manager/meta-release:

```
$ cat /etc/update-manager/meta-release
# default location for the meta-release file

[METARELEASE]
URI = http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release
URI_LTS = http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts
URI_UNSTABLE_POSTFIX = -development
URI_PROPOSED_POSTFIX = -proposed
```

What may be the problem of this?

Comment: whilst this is a 10.04 question - can you try any of the answers here and let us know the results? http://askubuntu.com/questions/8233/can-not-upgrade-server-edition

Comment: @fossfreedom I tried with no success. I've already had `update-manager-core` installed, and `prompt=normal`. I can update the successfully, but only dis-upgrade cannot find the next version.

Comment: can you pastebin.com your sources.list file please.

Comment: also - what is the contents of `/etc/update-manager/meta-release` ?

Comment: @fossfreedom I've added the contents of the files you mentioned.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 or Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on a server or system: install the `update-manager-core` package if it is not already installed; launch the upgrade tool with the command `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`; and follow the on-screen instructions. Note that the server upgrade is now more robust and will utilize GNU screen and automatically re-attach in case of e.g. dropped connection problems.

Comment: I'm not using 10.04 LTS but 11.04. But anyway, `sudo do-release-update -d` seems to do the work. The machine is now getting oneiric packages.

Comment: Glad i could help.

Comment: This worked OK here, but you should *not* use `-d` when attempting to upgrade to another stable release. `-d` will upgrade to a development release if one is available to upgrade to from the current release, which would be quite undesirable in a production environment. Just leave off the `-d` flag for normal upgrading.

Comment: Note that when `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` contains `Prompt=lts`, `sudo do-release-update -d` can be used to upgrade to a stable, non-lts, release. I'm currently at precise, have configured to only upgrade to the next lts , but `sudo do-release-update -d` will upgrade to quantal (which has long been stable at the time of writing)

Answer (score 28):

Check `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`

```
Prompt=lts
```

will cause upgrade to fail if the release you are currently on is **not** an LTS one.

**Solution:**

Change `Prompt=lts` to `Prompt=normal` and save the changes

Do the required upgrades until you have installed a LTS release.

Then change back to `Prompt=lts`

Done.

Comment: I already have this set to `prompt=normal`. I'm sorry I only mentioned this in one of the comments to the question.

Answer (score 7):

One possible reason is that the release available stamp file hangs around incorrectly. The following fixes this issue:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available
```

This file is safe to remove as it will be regenerated next time the motd script runs if appropriate.

---

Reason: this issue came up for me in 13.04 after a partially completed release upgrade which I completed with apt-get distupgrade. If the stamp file in `/var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available` exists and has a message that a new release is available, it is shown on every login via the motd script: `/etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade`, which calls `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd` to update the stamp if it's empty. See these files for more info on why this hangs around.

Comment: This is what worked for me, running `do-release-upgrade -d` tried to update to 13.10 dev release

Comment: In 12.04 the stale update file is in `/var/lib/update-notifier/` (not `ubuntu-release-upgrader/`), but everything else still applies.

Answer (score 4):

This can also happen if apt is configured to use a proxy and the proxy does not work properly. In my case the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy` contained the line

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxy.local:9999";
```

and the server `proxy.local` was not responding. Removing this line fixed the "No new release found" issue with the graphical and terminal update tool.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, a running 12.04 will not offer to upgrade to 12.10. The reason is because there are compatibility issues with my video hardware in 12.10. The tools told me after I tried to force the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem with 12.04 - > 13.04 and it was fixed by using `-d` option as guided coleman/Kagan above i.e.:

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```

Answer (score 0):

For old releases that have reached their EOL cycle, you can try this:

Download the meta-release info locally with this instruction: 
https://askubuntu.com/a/502485/34298

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to happen if you are using do-release-upgrade under socks client (proxychains or tsocks command). Your socks server or socks client does not support DNS lookup. Workaround for this is adding host entries to /etc/hosts file while distribution upgrade:

```
91.189.88.17    old-releases.ubuntu.com
91.189.92.201   archive.ubuntu.com
91.189.91.15    security.ubuntu.com
91.189.95.36    changelogs.ubuntu.com
```