# How to upgrade ubuntu server 11.04

Tags: command-line, upgrade

I want to upgrade my ubuntu server 64bit 11.04 to ubuntu 12.04. I tried to do it with the command:

$ do-release-upgrade

but the output is:

Checking for a new Ubuntu release
 No new release found

Does anybody know what the reason might be?

Comment: Please see this link 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/124999/distribution-upgrade-problem-no-new-release-found

Regards,
Haribabu Kasturi

Comment: Llook at haribabu's link - try with `do-release-upgrade -d` - also [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html)

Comment: Not really, @Aditya.

Comment: @wilf: Both the questions are possible causes.. OP might not have updated his `sources.list` file after 11.04 became EOL..

Answer (score 0):

Please Try, "sudo apt-get update", "sudo apt-get upgrade", "sudo update-manager -c" and let me know if you see it.