# I don't know how to upgrade 12.10 to 13.04 or 13.10

Tags: upgrade

I try to use upgrade app to upgrade, but the app tell me I can upgrade 13.10 directly.
But, if I press upgrade button, then the error message occured like...

**An upgrade from 'quantal' to 'saucy' is not supported with this tool.**

So, I try to upgrade with terminal by

```
    sudo do-release-upgrade
```

but, same error message occured.
I using 12.10 now. I want to upgrade to 13.10, but I can't upgrade 13.10, and 13.04.

------add------
I installed ubuntu 12.04 with Windows Installer, and I upgraded this to 12.10.

Comment: Plz keep in mind that op uses wubi.

Comment: This needs a new answer since 12.10 and 13.04 both are EOL by now

Comment: @rubo77 This does not need a new answer, since the only change is to use the old-releases archives (http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Then maybe you can post that as an answer with instructions how to change it correctly?

Comment: There are already several answers with instructions in [the  question that this duplicates](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 2):

First check which versions of `update-manager-core` are installed:

```
apt-cache policy update-manager-core
```

The result may be similar to this...

```
update-manager-core:
  Installed: 1:0.174.5
  Candidate: 1:0.174.5
  Version table:
 *** 1:0.174.5 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-proposed/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:0.174.4 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:0.174.3 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
```

... which means, that you have installed the package from `quantal-proposed`

By downgrading to the package from `quantal-updates` you should be able to upgrade to raring:

```
apt-get install update-manager-core=1:0.174.4 python3-update-manager=1:0.174.4
do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Download the meta-release info locally with

```
mkdir ~/upgrade
cd ~/upgrade
wget http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release

# change the sources to the old-release archives:
sed s/archive.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/ meta-release -i
sed -E '/\/(precise|trusty)/s/old-releases/archive/'  meta-release -i
# grab the release notes from old-releases.ubuntu.com while the LTS releases precise and trusty still live on archive.ubuntu.com
# the code block, -E triggers extended, | means "OR"

#enable all releases:
sed 's/Supported: 0/Supported: 1/' meta-release -i

# backup the system meta-release file:
sudo cp -a /etc/update-manager/meta-release etc-update-manager-meta-release.bak

# change the system meta-release path lo the local one on port 80:
sudo sed s/changelogs.ubuntu.com/127.0.0.1/ /etc/update-manager/meta-release -i

# change the LTS info in the same file
sudo sed s/meta-release-lts/meta-release/ /etc/update-manager/meta-release -i

# start serving your own meta-release locally with
sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
```

Now start the graphical update-notifier or open a new terminal with Ctrl+Shift+N and perform the release upgrade

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

### Cleaning-up

After the upgrade you must restore the system file `/etc/update-manager/meta-release`
with:

```
sudo cp -a etc-update-manager-meta-release.bak /etc/update-manager/meta-release
```

*source: https://askubuntu.com/a/135028/34298*

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just installing new version of Ubuntu on this partition from Live CD or USB. It will not erase everything as it could be expected. It leaves home folder - with applications settings and all other stuff like that and which, in my opinion, is the most important - and some application unharmed. As I remember, I tried it upgrading from 13.04 to 14.04 and it worked well.

And before You can always do 1:1 partition copy with GParted. Just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it from this direction:

Take a blank USB, download the Ubuntu version of your choosing, and then from Dash (accessible from the super key unless changed) choose 'Startup disk creator.' Create it to the blank USB, and then restart your computer making sure to enable boot from the USB. Once it booted to the install screen, follow the prompts choosing 'Upgrade to...'

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when trying to upgrade my 12.10 machine. Turns out it was actually caused by the **apt-cacher-ng proxy** that I use for caching package downloads. The proxy had cached an earlier version of `saucy.tar.gz` upgrade metadata, which said that upgrade from quantal is not supported.

So as a solution, log in to your *proxy machine* and run this:

```
sudo find /var/cache/apt-cacher-ng -name 'saucy.tar.gz*' -delete
```

If you don't have access to the proxy machine, then just comment out the Proxy line(s) in your `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

Why was the metadata changed? Because originally the upgrade path was 12.10 -> 13.04 -> 13.10. But support for 13.04 was dropped earlier than 12.10, so the new upgrade path is directly 12.10 -> 13.10. [(link)](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/01/ubuntu-13-04-end-of-life-january-27)

Answer (score 0):

update-manager-core does not currently work for upgrading to saucy (13.10) from quantal (12.10) ..

You need to modify your sources.list manually, and the run ap-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade ..