# Cannot upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 (No new release found)

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, update-manager, 16.10, do-release-upgrade

Cannot upgrade from 16.04LTS to 16.10.

Updated and dist-upgraded the system and tried running `do-release-upgrade -d` but it says **no release found**. Ensured that the `prompt=normal` in the "`/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`" file.

Tried the same using the GUI of update-manager and changed the settings to "Notify for any new version" which is equivalent of prompt = normal and it says **Your computer is up to date**.

Also, all the necessary repos are present in the sources.lists.

I have recently upgraded a similar computer successfully which was quite straightforward. Cannot understand why this is happening even though the config files are similar and there are no problems in installing/updating using apt-get.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: I deleted my answer because I saw that you already tried that.  I did find one that might help:  http://askubuntu.com/a/289076/231142

Comment: No such file exists. :/

Comment: Open `Software updater` it will give you option for upgrade to 16.10

Answer (score 7):

After changing the setting in `/etc/update-manager/releases-upgrades` from `lts` to `normal`, you need to run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Just for clarification, the `sudo apt-get update` forces it to check for new releases, _then_ you do `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10 from the current LTS you will need to tell the OS that you want to receive non-LTS updates.:

1. Open ‘Software & Updates’ using the Unity Dash
2. Select the ‘Updates‘ tab
3. Find the section titled ‘Notify me of a new Ubuntu version‘
4. Change this from ‘For long-term support versions’ to ‘For any new version‘
5. Click ‘Close’

You’ll instantly be prompted to run a quick update.

[image]

Comment: Tried, same as putting prompt = normal. No luck !

Comment: What `sudo apt-get update` says

Answer (score 0):

I found that my 16.04 box had a broken DNS (I had nothing in /etc/resolv.conf), so "sudo do-release-upgrade" fails with the "no release found" message mentioned above.

Once I fixed DNS, I got:

```
s1:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [836 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,265 kB]
Fetched 1,266 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'xenial.tar.gz' against 'xenial.tar.gz.gpg'
...
```

So a good test is "sudo apt-get update" to ensure you can actually reach update servers, or a simple "nslookup security.ubuntu.com" to validate DNS is working.